# Mark on PDF Android App

Tags: java, android, pdf, kotlin, marker

I'm currently developing an application on Android with AndroidPDFViewer : https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I want to create a functionality, when the user touch the screen, it put a point on the PDF at this location. After I want to measure the distance between 2 points but it's an other problem.
I don't understand how to do this functionality, put a point on PDF. I found this : https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/554

So it's possible but how ? I don't get it.
I suppose I need to create a bitmap, but I can't draw on the PDF, or put a marker.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sample file in his repo.

If you go to this [location](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/sample/PDFViewActivity.java) he has already created the method on how to load a pdf! Then if you go [to this link](https://github.com/xiasenhai/PdfiumAndroid/blob/6ebee0411705fd7771ad3ce5a23f53b1457b6b6d/src/main/java/com/shockwave/pdfium/PdfiumCore.java) you will see that he has created the class and has included good comments

```
Render page fragment on {@link Surface}
      Page must be opened before rendering.

    public void renderPage(PdfDocument doc, Surface surface, int pageIndex,
                           int startX, int startY, int drawSizeX, int drawSizeY) {
        renderPage(doc, surface, pageIndex, startX, startY, drawSizeX, drawSizeY, false);
    }
```

The one that you are searching is bookmark method

```
/** Get table of contents (bookmarks) for given document */
    public List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> getTableOfContents(PdfDocument doc) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> topLevel = new ArrayList<>();
            Long first = nativeGetFirstChildBookmark(doc.mNativeDocPtr, null);
            if (first != null) {
                recursiveGetBookmark(topLevel, doc, first);
            }
            return topLevel;
        }
    }
```

However keep in mind that it might be necessary to use Async Tasks to download a pdf!